# Splice doesn't delete any item from array - Angular12

Tags: slice, shopping-cart, angular12

I am trying create a function for deleting specific items from a shopping cart.
It doesn't give any errors, but when I click the button nothing happens. Any idea what might be the problem?
See the codes below about my issue.

service.ts

```
removeCartItem(product: Product){
    this.cartItemList.map((a:any, index:any)=>{
      if(product.id=== a.id){
        this.cartItemList.splice(index,1); 
      }
    })
```

cartitem.component.html

```
<div class="cartitem">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        {{ cartItem.name }}
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <img [src]="cartItem.imageUrl" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
      </div>
      <div class="col-5">
        {{ cartItem.description }}
      </div>
      <div class="col">{{ cartItem.price | currency: "EUR" }}</div>
      <div class="col">{{ cartItem.qty }}</div>
      <div>
        <button (click)="removeItem(item)" class="btn btn-primary">
          Remove from cart
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

cartitem.component.ts

```
  constructor(public service: MessengerService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
 removeItem(item: Product){
    this.service.removeCartItem(item);
  }
```

cart.component.ts

```
 cartItems: Product[] = [];

  cartTotal = 0;

  product: any;

  constructor(private msg: MessengerService, public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.msg.getMsg().subscribe((product: Product) => {
      this.addProductToCart(product);
    });
  }

  addProductToCart(product: Product) {
    let productExists = false;

    for (let i in this.cartItems) {
      if (this.cartItems[i].id === product.id) {
        this.cartItems[i].qty++;
        productExists = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!productExists) {
      this.cartItems.push({
        id: product.id,
        name: product.name,
        description: product.description,
        qty: 1,
        price: product.price,
        imageUrl: product.imageUrl,
        purchased:product.purchased
      });
    }
    this.cartItems.forEach((item) => {
      this.cartTotal += item.qty * item.price;
    });
  }
```

cart.component.html

```
<ul *ngIf="cartItems.length > 0" class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <h3>My Cart</h3>
  </li>

  <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let item of cartItems">
    <app-cartitem [cartItem]="item"></app-cartitem>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <span>Total: {{ cartTotal | currency: "EUR" }} </span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <button
      id="btnFinalize"
      class="btn btn-primary"
      (click)="purchaseDisabled(product)"
    >
      Finalize purchase
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your modification of the list is within the for loop. Use the loop to grab index then splice outside it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to splice inside map. Changing to the following will work:

```
removeCartItem(product: Product){
    let indexToRemove: number = -1;

    this.cartItemList.map((a:any, index:any)=>{
      if(product.id === a.id){
        indexToRemove = index;
      }

      return a;
    });
    
    if(indexToRemove !== -1){
       this.cartItemList.splice(indexToRemove,1); 
    }  
}
```

But notice there is no need to use map here. It's a waste of time and memory to copy the entire array again. Just a loop through the array to find the index to remove would be enough:

```
removeCartItem(product: Product){
    let indexToRemove: number = -1;
    let index: number = 0;

    for(const cardItem of this.cartItemList){
      if(product.id === cardItem.id){
        indexToRemove = index;
      }
      
      index++;
    }

    if(indexToRemove !== -1){
       this.cartItemList.splice(indexToRemove,1); 
    }  
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this way doesn't work either and throws 0 errors.

Comment: @BrigittaTóth Then, the problem might be elsewhere. I tested this piece here and it's working fine. Could you show the piece of code where you render the cart, please ?

Comment: I edited my post with cart.component.ts, you can check it out there.

Comment: @BrigittaTóth Add the HTML where you render the cart as well, please

Comment: Of course, I added it as well.

Comment: @BrigittaTóth In your `cartitem.component.html`, from where `item` comes from ?

Comment: I edited cartitem.component.html as well. Hope I understood you correctly.

Comment: @BrigittaTóth Shouldn't it be `<button (click)="removeItem(cartItem)" class="btn btn-primary">` ?

Comment: Checked with that also, no luck.